# How to copy/paste conditional formatting rules (into new columns) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

To help, I setup [this public spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15_bcxZZUYlTVcDzNZbNGerw8GkLbA4atj-aJNxzA8Vk/edit#gid=0).

We have the following conditional format rules

[image]

In the spreadsheet above, when we copy cells `A3:B7` into `C3`, what we want is for the conditional formatting rules to update to **=$C$2="AAA"**. However, we need to include the $ signs in order for the conditional formatting to work across the full 5x2 grid of boxes...

How can we setup this conditional formatting so that the copy/pasting of cells accurately copies the formatting rules? We want to copy `A3:B7` into both `C3` and `E3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you use this as a respective formula, it will do what you want. If you look in [your sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15_bcxZZUYlTVcDzNZbNGerw8GkLbA4atj-aJNxzA8Vk/edit#gid=1256711800), I put it on a separate tab.

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2)=0,INDIRECT("R2C[-1]",false),INDIRECT("R2C",false))="CCC"
```

#### UPDATED FOR Dynamic Top Row

If you don't want to hard code row 2 into the formula you can use a named range for the row, which will then update your formula if you want to insert rows.

In the same above worksheet, I created a named range for row 2 called `HeaderRow`. I then inserted some rows, pushing `HeaderRow` down to row 4 and the condition still works.

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2)=0,INDIRECT("R"&row(indirect("HeaderRow"))&"C[-1]",false),INDIRECT("R"&row(indirect("HeaderRow"))&"C",false))="CCC"
```

[image]

Comment: yep this works. indirect is a bit tough to work with. inserting a row at the top breaks the conditional formatting unless we update "R2C" to "R3C" in the format rules for example. But it still works, thanks so much

Comment: @Canovice, I upated the answer to take that into consideration. See my same sample sheet and note the named range combined with new condition rule of `=IF(MOD(COLUMN(),2)=0,INDIRECT("R"&row(indirect("HeaderRow"))&"C[-1]",false),INDIRECT("R"&row(indirect("HeaderRow"))&"C",false))="CCC"`